# Backbone Paginator - Using setFilter on more than 1 field

Tags: backbone.js

I have a backbone application which returns a paginated collection which I put into a table. I can apply a filter on 1 column at time as shown below:

View:

```
(function (views) {
    views.PaginatedView = Backbone.View.extend({
        events: {
            'click a.filter': 'filter'
        },
        getFilterField: function () {
            return $('#filterByOption').val();
        },
        getFilterValue: function () {
            return $('#filterString').val();
        },
        filter: function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var fields = this.getFilterField(); // returns a value from a dropdown
            var filter = this.getFilterValue(); // returns a value from my input
            this.collection.setFilter(fields, filter);
            this.collection.pager();
        }
    });
})(app.views);
```

Template:

```
<select id="filterByOption">
    <option value="Account">Account</option>
    <option value="Owner">Owner</option>
</select>

<span class="cell sort">
    <input id="filterString" type="text" class="cell" />
    <a href="#" class="filter btn small">Filter</a>
</span>
```

My problem is: I want to apply a further filter to further fields, but as far as I know, the `setFilter` function only allows 1 field per time to be filtered on. So for example: I want to filter on Account: 123, of which those have an Owner: Bob. At the moment I'm only able to filter on either Account or Owner.

Comment: No sorry, I abandoned this and used Knockout instead!

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with the setFilter method, but why dont you use underscore? An example would be:

```
var filteredContent = _.filter(this.collection, function(model)
{  
    return model.Account === 123 && model.Owner === "Bob"; 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can pass to `SeFilter` an array value for `fields`.

So for example you can avoid to use a select list and just set:

```
var fields = ["Account","Owner"];
```

Comment: Yes, but how do I filter against each of those fields? So Account: 123, Owner: Bob

Comment: I don't think you can with the current version of Backbone.Paginator. You should override its `_filter` method because actually it just cycle on every fields you set to match with the filter value.

Comment: Thats what I'm trying to do actually, I did look at the `setFieldFilter` function but I'm not sure how to use it?